# Jenkins, Executable and right

Tags: jenkins, executable

It seems that i have a permission problem to execute a .exe under windows with jenkins.

**Things to know about the system:**

- I have a windows user called 'Tester'. This user has Administrator rights
- Jenkins run as a service using Tester username
- I have a job which does the following:

  ```
  cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\sahi\tools
  toggle_IE_proxy.exe enable
  ```

The process is silent, no output. The executable must probably change some values in registry.

This command tick the checkbox "Use a proxy..."[image: Proxy checkbox]

**Note:** it is working fine when i execute the command above in a cmd.exe as user 'Tester'.

Do you have an idea what's happening there ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that turning Off UAC solved my problem